Structure of nested Divs with a table
I'm a new frontend programmer.
I'm making a web site with flask, and to be honest, I don't know much about front-end so I don't know if what I'm doing is best practices. In one section, I have a div containing other divs with a table.
My concern is if I'm using the right structure for that, so that's why I'm asking people with more expertise in this field.  I changed some things so it would be pureHTML, CSS and JS, but the data in the table appears dynamically if there is some data in the data base.


  function validate() {
    // check if input is bigger than 3
    var value = document.getElementById("expense-name").value;
    if (value.length < 1) {
      return false; // keep form from submitting
    }

    // else form is good let it submit, of course you will
    // probably want to alert the user WHAT went wrong.

    return true;
  }
body{
    background-color: bisque;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


/* index.html */
/* Container to center the div container */
.super-container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    
    
}
/* Centering the container */
.container{
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: flex-start;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 1%;
    min-height: 30vh;
    width: 78vw;
    background-color: white;
}

/* Deletes the arrows of inputs fields */
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    /* display: none; <- Crashes Chrome on hover */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0; /* <-- Apparently some margin are still there even though it's hidden */
}

input[type=number] {
    appearance:textfield; /* Firefox */
}


/* Adding border, padding, and font size of caption to table*/
.container h2{
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.container td{
    border: 1px groove rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.178);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 5px;
}

.container table{
    margin: 10px auto;
    height: 50%;
    border: 2px groove rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.178);
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 70%
}

.container th{
    border: 1px groove rgba(236, 0, 0, 0.178);
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    padding: 10px 45px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50%;
}
<div class="super-container">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Expense Tracker</h2>
    <form action="/" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="test" required />
      <input type="number" name="amount" placeholder="Amount" required />
      <select name="category" id="">
        <option>Opcion 1</option>
      </select>
      <input type="date" name="date" />
      <input type="submit" name="" id="" />
    </form>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Expense Name</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Test1</td>
        <td>Test1</td>
        <td>Test1</td>
        <td>Test1</td>
        <td>
          <form
            action="{{ url_for('delete_item', id=expense.id)}}"
            method="POST"
          >
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
          </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>




My concern is if I'm using the right structure  =>  Be sure to search StackExchange there's years of wisdom in here. For example Create HTML table for Javascript object.  "structure" is the right way to think about it. Evolutionary changes with language and libraries likewise evolves technique and there is room for preferences, yet utilizing Objects well will  stand the test of time and change.

LGTM -- ship it.
